# Open .ISM with InstallShield Limited Edition

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installshield-2010

Environment: TFS 2010 + VisualStudio 2010 + InstallShield Limited Edition.

I am sorry to be novice about InstallShield.

I have a InstallShield project with .ISM extension. Is it possible to load it in InstallShield Limited Edition. I tried but it is not recognizing the .ISM extension.

I tried to create New InstallShield project using InstallShield Limited Edition. It generates .ISL and .ISPROJ extensions instead of .ISM.

- What is .ISM (IF InstallShield is creating .ISL and .ISPROJ project
  files)?
- How can I work on .ISM InstallShield setup (project) , using
  InstallShield Limited Edition (if possible)?

My minimum requirement is to look into the existing setup , even if not enabled to build and generate an MSI.

Thanks and Regards
Sumeet Nandan Garg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

InstallShield limited edition cannot import, open, or build projects created in a paid edition of InstallShield. In order to get a better idea what is in that project, you might try evaluating the Professional or Premier edition of InstallShield. If you find that you need anything beyond the capability set of the Limited Edition, you will likely need to purchase the Professional or Premier edition.