# Visual Studio 2015 open .ism file

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installshield

I installed installshield and re-opened my visual studio 2015. I'd like to open a installshield project which ends with .ism. However, explorer in visual studio couldn't find this project. This link is the suggestion that I am following. But got stuck on step 4.
https://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?203223-Opening-InstallShield-Projects-in-Microsoft-Visual-Studio

Comment: In explorer I specified "all files", but that .ism file doesn't show up. It seems visual studio still cannot recognize this project.

Comment: Installshield in visual studio 2015 creates files with .isproj and .isl extension, while the olde version create files with .ism extension. So is there any way to re-use my old file?

Comment: [You are using the wrong license](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932520/open-ism-with-installshield-limited-edition).